# Want to find available month between two dates using sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want the unique month between two date
like

```
@StartDate = '04-05-2013'
@EndDate = '26-12-2013'
```

I want the output like

```
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

I also want to use cursor with above output how to get this using sql server

Comment: Well, did you try anything? If yes, then share please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you may use a script like the following in order to obtain the values you are looking for. I can't understand whether you would need a single result set or not, so the script simply returns one result set for each month: feel free to modify it as you need, even by mixing the code with your (existing?) cursor-related script:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2013-05-04' 
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2013-12-26'

WHILE (@StartDate < @EndDate)
BEGIN
    SELECT MONTH(@StartDate)

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(month, 1, @StartDate)
END
```

Also please note this is a starting point: for performance reasons, you may want to somehow consider reviewing the entire query.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need months number then you can get the difference of months between two dates and increment it to get the result as shown below:

```
DECLARE @StartDateMonth int = DATEPART(mm, '2013-05-04') 
DECLARE @EndDateMonth int =  DATEPART(mm,'2013-12-26')

WHILE (@StartDateMonth <= @EndDateMonth )
BEGIN
    SELECT @StartDateMonth
    SET @StartDateMonth = @StartDateMonth + 1

END
```